# add-migration doesnt recognize new fields for aspnetuser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

MVC 5 project.

For registered users I want to also support FirstName and LastName fields.

So, first, I added 2 new fields to IdentityModel.cs....

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The problem: When I run the "add-migration" command in PMC (which I've used alot in this project) it doesn't show that anything needs to be added to the database. No errors either. Any idea why?

I could add it manually via SQL Server but that defeats the purpose I guess.

FYI: This may or may not matter, but, I am using fluent api mappings for my models. Would I have to also add these fields to AspNetUser.cs and then to mappings as well? Online it appears I only have to add the new Identity fields to IdentityModel.cs.

Thanks

Comment: What does your context inherit from?

Comment: @DavidG My context inherits from DbContext.

Comment: So how are you using Identity? Are you sure it doesn't inherit from `IdentityDbContext`?

Comment: @DavidG my bad. Yes, it appears that it does: public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>